# Remove columns with certain number of zeros - R

Tags: r

How can I remove columns with more than 6 zeros in my data?

Please let me know how I can make my sample code achieve what I need to do, and if you have a shorter way, please let me know that as well. Explaining and teaching me why it works would also be appreciated.

My sample code to remove zeros:

```
removeThese = c()
for(i in 1:ncol(myData))
{
rowsWithZeros = which(myData[,i] == 0)
if(length(rowsWithZeros) > 6)
{
removeThese = c(removeThese, i)
}
}
myData= myData[,-removeThese]
```

Comment: Is it a matrix or a data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to shorten the number of lines, replacing  for loop with an appropriate *apply statement works well.

```
sixZeroes = function(col) {
  sum(col==0)>6
}

myData=myData[,apply(myData,2,sixZeroes)]
```

The function can be inline, if you want a one-liner.

Comment: what is the 2 for? myData=myData[,apply(myData,2,sixZeroes)]

Comment: It's the MARGIN argument in the apply function. Take a look at `?apply`

Comment: oh i see! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
i <- colSums(myData == 0, na.rm=TRUE) < 7
myData <- myData[, i, drop=FALSE]
```

or, following Richard

```
i <- colSums(myData == 0, na.rm=TRUE) < 7
myData <- myData[i]
```

Comment: If you use list subsetting you won't need `drop`, like `data[colSums(data == 0, na.rm = TRUE) <  7]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe:

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x==0)<=6, df)
```